# Data acquisition using QuantTools with R

Tags: r

I am using the QuantTools package in R language
When get_finam_data () is used, how can I obtain a list of symbols that can be acquired?

Answer (score 1):

You should go to package internals to get the list. 
Just download data for arbitrary symbol so the list is fetched from Finam server and saved for later use. 
Keep in mind this is not documented so it can be changed in future versions.

```
get_finam_data( 'GAZP', Sys.Date() )
QuantTools:::finam_downloader_env$instruments_info
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there no way to get it from QuantTools package. You can get it from https://www.finam.ru/profile/moex-akcii/mosenrg/export/?market=1 by hand or use external web sources.